# ASP.NET: How to user the UploadFile Control inside ListView Control for uploading document in the web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-controls

I am developing a web application using ASP.NET. Now, I am working on the administrative tasks and I want to give the admin the ability to upload newsletter which will be displayed on one of the web application pages. I am trying to use a ListView Control and UploadFile Control inside the ListView. **Everything works fine in this manner except there is something wrong in the code-behind this is way I am not able to upload anything and show it in the listView.**

Part from ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="NewsletterID" 
             DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" 
             oniteminserting="ListView1_ItemInserting">

             <InsertItemTemplate>
                 <tr style="">
                     <td>
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="InsertButton" ImageUrl="images/insert.png" Width="20px" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" />

                         <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="images/clear3.png" Width="20px" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />

                         <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("Username") %>' OnPreRender="LoadUsername" />
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="NewsletterTitleTextBox" runat="server" 
                             Text='<%# Bind("NewsletterTitle") %>' />
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload1" runat="server" size="10" />
                     <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("Url") %>' /> 
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </InsertItemTemplate>
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <tr style="">
                     <td>
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="images/delete.png" Width="20px" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                         <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="images/edit.png" Width="20px" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="NewsletterTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NewsletterTitle") %>' />
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <a href='<%# Eval("Url") %>' target="_blank">
                         <asp:Label ID="UrlLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Url") %>' />
                         </a>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </ItemTemplate>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
             ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
             DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Newsletter] WHERE [NewsletterID] = @NewsletterID" 
             InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Newsletter] ([NewsletterTitle], [Url], [Username]) VALUES (@NewsletterTitle, @Url, @Username)" 
             SelectCommand="SELECT Newsletter.NewsletterID, Newsletter.NewsletterTitle, Newsletter.Url, Newsletter.Username FROM Newsletter INNER JOIN employee ON Newsletter.Username = employee.Username" 
             UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Newsletter] SET [NewsletterTitle] = @NewsletterTitle, [Url] = @Url, [Username] = @Username WHERE [NewsletterID] = @NewsletterID">
             <DeleteParameters>
                 <asp:Parameter Name="NewsletterID" Type="Int32" />
             </DeleteParameters>
             <InsertParameters>
                 <asp:Parameter Name="NewsletterTitle" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Url" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
             </InsertParameters>
             <UpdateParameters>
                 <asp:Parameter Name="NewsletterTitle" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Url" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="NewsletterID" Type="Int32" />
             </UpdateParameters>
         </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

the Modified Code-behind (in C#):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void LoadUsername(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((HiddenField)sender).Value = Service.User.ID;
}

protected void ListView1_ItemInserting(object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    ListView lv = (ListView)sender;
    FileUpload fUpload = (FileUpload)lv.InsertItem.FindControl("fileUpload1");
    //string path = ("UploadedPix\\" + fUpload.FileName);
    //var tempPath = "some-temp-path-";
    var tempFile = fUpload.FileName;

    if (fUpload.HasFile)
    {
        try {
            fUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + tempFile);
            HiddenField hField= (HiddenField)lv.InsertItem.FindControl("HiddenField2");
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

After modifying the code-behind a little bit, I got the following error:

***Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Url', table 'psspdb.dbo.Newsletter'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.***

This ListView is bound to the Newsletter table in the database. The structure of this table is as following:
NewsletterID, NewsletterTitle, url, Username

the Username is a foreign key to the Username in the Usre Table. The newsletter will be in pdf format. What I want is letting the admin specify title of the newsletter that will be appear to the user before he clicks on this link to download or preview the newsletter.

Comment: Can you describe the error you are getting?

Comment: Isn't this error because you are not assigning url to HiddenField2 (the hField variable in code-behind)?

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self explanatory. The url field is blank on insert. Try making the url field accept nulls. Then try the insert/upload and see if it works. Once you know the upload works, You can come back and then work the url field and value.